# UIColor Components

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I'm trying to extract components of UIColor objects and have the following code:

```
    var red1:CGFloat = 0
    var green1:CGFloat = 0
    var blue1:CGFloat = 0
    var alpha1:CGFloat = 0

    var red2:CGFloat = 0
    var green2:CGFloat = 0
    var blue2:CGFloat = 0
    var alpha2:CGFloat = 0

    var bool1 = color1.getRed(&red1, green: &green1, blue: &blue1, alpha: &alpha1)
    var bool2 = color2.getRed(&red2, green: &green2, blue: &blue2, alpha: &alpha2)

    var components = CGColorGetComponents(color1.CGColor)
    NSLog("Color1 Components Method: %f, %f, %f, %f", components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3])

    NSLog((bool1 == true) ? "YES" : "NO")
    NSLog((bool2 == true) ? "YES" : "NO")

    var alpha:CGFloat = (1 - (1 - alpha1) * (1 - alpha2))
    if (alpha < 1.0e-6) {
        return UIColor.clearColor()
    }

    NSLog("Color1: %@", color1)
    NSLog("%f, %f, %f %f", red1, green1, blue1, alpha1)

    NSLog("Color2: %@", color2)
    NSLog("%f, %f, %f %f", red2, green2, blue2, alpha2)
```

However, all the components evaluate to zero and I'm not sure why. Here is the output:

```
   2014-09-22 21:03:22.923 Colors[46574:589980] Color1 Components Method: 0.000000,    0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
   2014-09-22 21:03:22.923 Colors[46574:589980] YES
   2014-09-22 21:03:22.923 Colors[46574:589980] YES
   2014-09-22 21:03:22.924 Colors[46574:589980] Color1: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1
   2014-09-22 21:03:22.924 Colors[46574:589980] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000 0.000000
   2014-09-22 21:03:22.924 Colors[46574:589980] Color2: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1
   2014-09-22 21:03:22.924 Colors[46574:589980] 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000 0.000000
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: How are `color1` and `color2` defined?

Comment: I've tried defining color1/color2 using the system color methods UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.redColor() respectively. I've also tried using UIColor(red:green:blue:alpha) which doesn't produce any different results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values aren't zero, they're just printing that way since you're printing a `CGFloat` as a `Float`.  To fix it:

```
NSLog("%f, %f, %f, %f", Float(red1), Float(green1), Float(blue1), Float(alpha1))
```

or

```
NSLog("%@, %@, %@, %@", red1, green1, blue1, alpha1)
```

or

```
println("\(red1), \(green1), \(blue1), \(alpha1)")
```

Comment: Ahhh, thanks! Although I thought the format specifier %@ was for object types.